# Copy SDF file from WP8 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I need to copy a `.sdf` SQL Server CE database file from my WP 8 device to my computer. How can I do that?

Using the WP8 Emulator and Isolated Explorer i can copy from my emulator but I need to copy from my real device.

Regards

JR

Comment: Probably can register your app for .sdf file; Then copy the .sdf to the SD Card.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware could you please give me more details how can I do this :

Comment: sure, let me find the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get the contents of my db from my device: Windows Phone Power Tools do this!

http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can write the database file to the SD Card.

[MSDN : SD Card Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx) : Make sure you have `removableStorage` capability in app manifest.

You also might need to associate your app to handle the file extension you want to copy to the SD Card.

[MSDN : File associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

---

Let me know how it goes or if you need more help.